# How to include the the database in making .py into .exe?

Tags: python, database, pyinstaller, exe, mysql-python

Hi I tried exporting my database into .sql then place it in same folder with my .py file hoping that when I make my .py into an executable file my the .sql will built into the .exe

But this didn't seem to work out because when I drop the database I used in my .py then run the executable file it wont run.

[heres my folder where I do the pyinstaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4Mcm.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can add external data by using `--add-data` in commandline. The example from the [docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html):

```
pyinstaller --add-data 'src/README.txt:.' myscript.py
```

Or directly in the spec file :

```
added_files = [
     ( 'src/README.txt', '.' ),
     ( '/mygame/sfx/*.mp3', 'sfx' )
      ]
a = Analysis(...
     datas = added_files,
     ...
     )
```

If you want to do a one-file exe, also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/13790741#13790741).